# understand of Max Number of TCP Connections in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

In nifi, under the syslog processor, there is one attribute of Max Number of TCP Connections and the default value is 2. I took a look at the source code: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/da6ad4f3bcdeb43783aafa9f8942c5fa2a7da20b/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ListenSyslog.java#L300 and I'm trying to figure out what this attribute is really about. Is it the max number of tcp connection that can connect to a single processor simultaneously? So in my 3 node nifi cluster, I have allow maximum 6 tcp connection at the same time on port 5100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it is the maximum number of TCP connection that can connect so a single ListenSyslog processor simultaneously, on a given host.

So in a 3 node cluster, with one ListenSyslog on the canvas, then each node has one ListenSystlog that can handle 2 simultaneous connections on that node, for a total of 6 across the cluster.

It essentially equates to how many threads are available to read from connections simultaneously.

Comment: An follow up question in this thread, what would be the impact if I change Max Number of TCP Connections to a higher number? Will that putting more pressure on the Memory only or there will be more side effect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each additional thread will use a little more memory and will use more CPU cycles. That being said, 2 is a very low conservative number and I would think you could increase it a bit on most systems.

Comment: @BryanBende How do I calculate the number of tcp connections required?

Comment: @BryanBende Should I increase the number of concurrent task or increase the number of tcp connections to improve the performance

Comment: @youcanlearnanything the # of TCP connections is based on how many clients you have sending data, if you have 10 clients then you need 10 Max TCP Connections

Comment: @BryanBende I am using ListenSyslog processor. How do I derive the values for max socket buffer and receive buffer size?